how can a Rust trait declare that a function which accepts &mut T will have at most a non-mut &T embedded in its return value?
I have some code that I have simplified to the following
struct X<'a> {
    a: &'a i32,
}

trait Bacon {
    type Y<'a: 'b, 'b>;
    fn blerp<'a, 'b>(s: &'b mut X<'a>) -> Self::Y<'a, 'b>;
}

fn main() {}

fn doot(x: &X) {
    println!("{}", x.a);
}

fn orange<B: Bacon>(x: &mut X, bacon: &B) {
    let y = B::blerp(x);

    doot(x);
}

This results in the following compile error:
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/gamma.rs:19:10
   |
17 |     let y = B::blerp(x);
   |                      - mutable borrow occurs here
18 |
19 |     doot(x);
   |          ^ immutable borrow occurs here
20 | }
   | - mutable borrow might be used here, when `y` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `<B as Bacon>::Y<'_, '_>`

I think this is because Rust is worried that the return value of blerp could contain &mut X.
In my specific use case the most I will ever need to hang on to is &X, so the call to doot should be safe.  How do I declare this fact in the trait?

Even if there was syntax for what you wanted, the code in orange would be rejected anyways. An immutable reference derived from a mutable reference does not relax the mutable reference - the immutable reference keeps the mutable reference alive. So x would not be able to be used while y is alive.
Look at this example with concrete types:
fn blerp<'a>(x: &'a mut i32) -> &'a i32 {
    x
}

fn doot(x: &i32) {
    println!("{}", x);
}

fn orange(x: &mut i32) {
    let y = blerp(x);

    doot(x);

    // explicit drop to mimic the constraints of using an associated type
    drop(y); 
}

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:12:10
   |
10 |     let y = blerp(x);
   |                   - mutable borrow occurs here
11 |
12 |     doot(x);
   |          ^ immutable borrow occurs here
...
15 |     drop(y);
   |          - mutable borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.

You can see that the error annotates drop(y) as a use of a mutable borrow even though y is an immutable reference.
One final note: this is not a failing of the borrow checker - this behavior is intended. A mutable reference is exclusive which means it can sometimes access values which could not otherwise via a shared reference. Even if access to those values are not mutable, the fact that you accessed them only via a mutable reference means that exclusivity must continue to be held.

Classic example: Cell::from_mut() and friends.

It works if you remove the lifetime from the mutable reference in the argument:
trait Bacon {
    type Y<'a: 'b, 'b>;
    fn blerp<'a, 'b>(s: &mut X<'a>) -> Self::Y<'a, 'b>;
}

playground

But it doesn't mean the same thing. When you remove the lifetime, the returned value can no longer keep a reference to s.

The returned value Self::Y<'a, 'b> lives for 'a: 'b, which is the duration of the function orange() when called there. Since 'a: 'b also the borrow of x in the call to blerp() lives for 'b, the mutable borrow of x lives as long as y does, i.e. for the entire duration of orange(). Hence you cannot use it after B::blerp(x). You can introduce a scope to prevent that.
Playground

Your code compiles, but I happen to need y to outlive the call to doot (my sample code did not make that clear).

The problem is that the destructor of variable y would run after call doot(x) so during the call of doot references x and in y alias.
You can solve that by either causing y to be dropped earlier:
fn orange<B: Bacon>(x: &mut X, bacon: &B) {
    let y = B::blerp(x);
    drop(y);
    doot(x);
}

or using scope to make it dropped automatically
fn orange<B: Bacon>(x: &mut X, bacon: &B) {
    {
      let y = B::blerp(x);
    }
    doot(x);
}

or by telling compiler that type Y doesn't need to be dropped by making it Copy:
trait Bacon {
    type Y<'a: 'b, 'b>: Copy;
    fn blerp<'a, 'b>(s: &'b mut X<'a>) -> Self::Y<'a, 'b>;
}


fn orange<B: Bacon>(x: &mut X, bacon: &B) {
    {
        // introduce a scope here
        let y = B::blerp(x);
    }// the borrow of `x` is release here
    doot(x);
}

